# If-statement generated by CoffeeScript always evaluates TRUE in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, if-statement, coffeescript

The issue I'm seeing is regarding the execution of the if-statement in the last if-statement in the code that I've listed below (`if (this._sortDirection === 'desc') ...`). If I run this code in Chrome (36.0.1985.125), things function as they should, but when run in Firefox (v31.0 on Mac OSX 10.9.4) the if-statement evaluates the condition incorrectly and always evaluates as if the condition was `true`. I've verified that this is not happening in Chrome and that it is indeed isolated to Firefox.

As part of my debugging, I replaced `@reverse() if @_sortDirection == 'desc'` with the following in the CoffeeScript code:

```coffee
`if (this._sortDirection === 'desc') {
  this.reverse();
}`
```

Which generates the following JavaScript:

```js
if (this._sortDirection === 'desc') {
  this.reverse();
};
```

After doing this, everything worked! I'm wondering if perhaps there is an encoding issue that Firefox isn't handling well and Chrome is because this code (except for the trailing `;` after the if-statement) is identical but one works and the other does not. I even placed both the inline code and the coffeescript code in the CoffeeScript file at the same time and verified that one is evaluated correctly while the other is not.

I obviously have a work around for this, but **I want to know if this is an issue with CoffeeScript or with Firefox or with my code and if it is an issue with my code...how do I fix it?** Obviously, I have a mountain of if-statements in my code and using this workaround is not a feasible solution, I would love to report it to be fixed if I can. I've already checked the CoffeeScript project issues and couldn't find anything there that resembled this issue.

Thanks for the help.

---

Here is my CoffeeScript code (for a full example see [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsara/m3d6T/)):

```coffee
sortObjects: ->
  return unless @_sortOn?
  @sort (obj1, obj2) =>
    return  1 if obj1[@_sortOn] > obj2[@_sortOn]
    return -1 if obj1[@_sortOn] < obj2[@_sortOn]
    return  0
  @reverse() if @_sortDirection == 'desc' # This is the line that is causing problems
  return
```

Here is what is generated at compile time:

```js
MyObject.prototype.sortObjects = function() {
  var _this = this;
  if (this._sortOn == null) {
    return;
  }
  this.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1[_this._sortOn] > obj2[_this._sortOn]) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (obj1[_this._sortOn] < obj2[_this._sortOn]) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  if (this._sortDirection === 'desc') { // This is the if-statement that is causing problems
    this.reverse();
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you include a functional example (i.e. any necessary missing methods and some data) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @muistooshort it seems that I'm having trouble duplicating this in jsFiddle and jsBin. http://jsfiddle.net/bsara/m3d6T/. I am using Ember.js 1.4.0 which could make a difference considering how much that framework adds stuff to your objects.

Comment: Where are you defining `@sortDirection`? How is it initialised?

Comment: @AlexP see this JSFiddle for an answer to your question: jsfiddle.net/bsara/m3d6T Refer to the `sortOn` method

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle; you should probably add that to the original question, as it's a useful debugging tool. For what it's worth, I can't reproduce the problem in Firefox on my system (v30, Linux); only one div, "Finished", shows up.